# Wahrscheinlich vs. wohl

Tags: grammar, modal-particle

1. ***Er hat wohl Recht  über die Zu-Wortstellung.***
   *He is probably right about the zu-construction.*
2. ***Wo ging er hin? - Er ging wahrscheinlich in die Kneipe, um einen heben.***
   *Where did he go? - He probably went to the pub to have a drink.*

Can I use ***wahrscheinlich*** instead of ***wohl***?
Are *"wohl"* and *"wahrscheinlich"* interchangeable?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yea, `wohl` can be used that way, also according to Duden. Personally, I'd say `wohl` is more colloquial here.

Side note: It must be

> Er ging wahrscheinlich in die Kneipe, um einen *zu* heben.

Answer (score 5):

Fully agreeing to *PMF*'s answer I'd like to add that those two words are not synonyms in the common sense.

Although they are exchangeable in the context given by the OP, they are not anymore if used with the adverb `sehr`.

As `sehr wahrscheinlich` means what expected, that is `most probably`, so still `not really sure`, using `sehr wohl` simply means `sure` in an achknowleding sense.

So `sehr wahrscheinlich` and `sehr wohl` are **not** the same.

> Er ging sehr wahrscheinlich in die Kneipe, ...
>
> He most probably went to the pub, ...

> Er ging sehr wohl in die Kneipe, ...
>
> He did go to the pub, ...